# How to select element with specific attribute name and then select its secondary attribute

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this xml feed, as below:

```
<GSP VER="3.2">
    <TM>0</TM>
    <Q>blue&blue</Q>
    <PARAM name="output" value="xml_no_dtd" original_value="xml_no_dtd"/> 
    <PARAM name="q" value="blue&blue" original_value="blue%26blue"/>
</GSP>
```

I then have the following jquery to iterate over this xml feed:

```
var queryresults = $(data).find("GSP").find("PARAM[q]");
var query = "";

$(queryresults).each(function() {
    query = $(this).attr('original_value').text();
    alert(query);
});
```

But I seem to be getting no return, how do you select a specific element with a specific attribute and then selects secondary attribute. For example

Select `"<PARAM>"` WITH attribute=`"name"` AND retrieve the value=`"original_value"`

Outcome:

```
query=blue%26blue
```

Comment: In your question the `value` attribute *isn't* equal to the `original_value` attribute; is that intentional, or am I misreading your question?

Comment: The question is confusing in that you selected an answer that doesn't select param based on two different attribute values.  Can you update the question to better reflect what it was you were looking for?

Comment: @DavidThomas - intentional and irrelevant, I just wanted to select the value whether its name is "micky" or "mouse".

Comment: @lucuma - I'm not sure what you mean, I didn't care to outputting the "name" attribute only the "value" attribute. Think the question reflected that, but feel free to put your own edit if you think its confusing.

Comment: You explicitly wrote: `Select "<PARAM>" WITH attribute="name" AND value="original_value"`   I will remove that line since that is obviously not what you were wanting.  You want to select based on one attribute and then retrieve the value of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code to look like this:

```
var queryresults = $(data).find("GSP").find("PARAM[name=q]");
var query = "";

$(queryresults).each(function() {
    query = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(query);
});
```

What you were trying to do with the .text() function was not necessary as the .attr() function already returns the value of that attribute.

Also, in order to find elements based on name, you could use the following:

```
$("PARAM[name=q]")
```

This is will also work with other attributes.

Useful reading: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the `query=` part of your expected output is supposed to come from, but otherwise, to retrieve the `blue%26blue` string from the above:

```
var originalValue = $('param[name="q"]').attr('original_value');
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

To select by multiple attributes:

`$('param[name="whatever"][value="whatever2"]')`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var queryresults = $("GSP").find("PARAM[name='q']"); // try it using "data"
var query = "";
$(queryresults).each(function() {
  query = $(this).attr('original_value');
  alert(query)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jHtg4/